# CREATE TABLE with FK and index options declarations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

MS SQL Server is giving the following error message on the WITH that preceeds the index options for the dbo.Calendar table:
"Incorrect syntax near the word 'WITH'".
When the FK declaration is disabled then the error goes away.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Scenario
(
  ScenarioKey           int           NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1),
  ScenarioName          varchar(60)   NOT NULL

  CONSTRAINT [PK-C_dbo.Scenario] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ScenarioKey)

  WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
        FILLFACTOR = 100,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,        
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
        )
    ON [PRIMARY]
);
GO
```

Works. But the following fails

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar
(
  ScenarioKey           int             NOT NULL,
  Bucket                smalldatetime   NOT NULL,
  BucketEnd             smalldatetime   NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT [PK-C_dbo.Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ScenarioKey, Bucket),

  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Calendar_dbo.Scenario] FOREIGN KEY (ScenarioKey)
    REFERENCES dbo.Scenario (ScenarioKey)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE

  WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
        FILLFACTOR = 100,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,        
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
        )
    ON [PRIMARY]  
);
GO
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
  WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, /*... */ ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON )
```

defines options for the index associated with the PK constraint not the foreign key. So it needs to go as part of the PK constraint definition. You are trying to include it as part of the FK definition. It should be

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar
  (
     ScenarioKey INT NOT NULL,
     Bucket      SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
     BucketEnd   SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK-C_dbo.Calendar] 
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ScenarioKey, Bucket)
      WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
             FILLFACTOR = 100, 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
             STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ),
     CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Calendar_dbo.Scenario] 
                FOREIGN KEY (ScenarioKey) 
     REFERENCES dbo.Scenario (ScenarioKey) ON DELETE CASCADE 
                                           ON UPDATE CASCADE
  )
ON [PRIMARY]
```